# SharePoint Online Removing HTTP Headers for Security Reasons

Tags: sharepoint-online, http-headers

I want to know if it's possible to hide the below HTTP Headers displayed by SharePoint Online site :

1. HTTP/1.1 200 OK
2. Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
3. X-AspNet Version : 4.0.30319
4. MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices : 16.0.0.20802
5. It is also observed that OPTIONS, DELETE and GETLIB methods are travelling every time in the application request.

These needs to be removed from security point of view.

Your early response will be highly appreciable. Thanks in advance.

Comment: None of those are security issues. Removing them is security by obscurity, at best. Everything is on .sharepoint.com; it's already obvious what the target system is running!

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to remove HTTP headers returned in SharePoint Online. More information on SharePoint Online data security can be found here:

[How SharePoint and OneDrive safeguard your data in the cloud](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/safeguarding-your-data)

Answer (score 0):

With **SharePoint Online** you **have no direct access to** the **web.config** files, **IIS**, or to deploy custom code solutions. So, it´s not possible remove **HTTP Headers** in **SharePoint online**.

If you are worried about SharePoint Online Security, you could read this article:

- [How SharePoint and OneDrive safeguard your data in the cloud](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/safeguarding-your-data)